# OpenCV VideoWriter saves the video faster than original frame rate

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I am trying to read a video file, process it, and save another video file with the same frame rate, bit rate, and length as the original one. But the output video becomes different. Here is the code sample:

```cpp
//int frameRate = (int)video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int frameRate = 30;
VideoWriter write1("./results/vname_result.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'), frameRate, frame.size(), true);

while (key != 'q'){
    video >> frame;

    write1 << frame;
    key = cvWaitKey(1);
}

write1.release();
```

The original video and the output video both have frame rate of 30. However, the other settings are different.

left: original

right: output

[image]

Should I set the **Total bitrate** in videWriter as well as **fps**?

Comment: suspicious is that the factor looks quite exactly to be 2. Is your input video interlaced?

Comment: @Micka no it is a normal avi video. When I set the output frame rate to be 15 (half of input) the length of video is fine (the same as input video). However, the bit rate is different (10368 kbps for output). When I set the output frame rate to be 30 (the same as input) the length becomes half and the speed is double.

Comment: can you post some sample images of the input? If possible from a fast moving camera or object scene

Comment: @Micka I can send some sample images, but this happens with every video as input, while the videos are completely different. I don't think the problem is with the input video.

Comment: Have you tried to change the format of a saved video? OpenCV uses the codecs that are installed in the system. Change CV_FOURCC into MJPG and let us know what happened. With MJPG each frame is compressed separately as a JPG file, in MP4 the frames are compressed in groups (GOP structure). So if it is related to compression scheme, changing it into MJPG will help.

Comment: @Sushi thank you for your suggestion. I changed the compression format to MJPG, but the same thing happened. The length of output video is half of the input, even though their frame rate is similar.

Comment: Could you post the video?

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=qklHKL

Comment: Can you post the total number of frames in both videos? Open the video using cv2.VideoCapture and use `print(cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))`